# Windows property sheet Shell extension with worker thread

Tags: windows, shell-extensions

I'm thinking of writing a Win32 Shell extension that adds a page to the Properties dialog for drives and folders.  This page would display information that *may* be expensive to acquire.  Because of this, I would want to put the data acquisition logic into a worker thread so as not to disrupt the UI, and to display feedback for the user on the page in question.  The page would be initialised, and thus trigger the data acquisition process, when the user selects the page (tab) in the Properties dialog.  After reading the relevant MSDN documentation, it is not clear to me how one would go about integrating a worker thread into a property sheet page for the Shell-created Properties dialog.

Ordinarily, I would have used either `PostThreadMessage` to post a private message to the message loop in the UI thread from the worker thread or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` in the UI thread and signalled a synchronisation event from the worker thread to indicate a unit of work had been done and the UI feedback mechanism (say, a progress meter) should be updated.  However, they both require integration into the message loop, which in the case of the Shell's Properties dialog, is predefined.

I notice that when I bring up the standard Properties dialog from Windows Explorer on a folder and it displays a count of the sub-folders and files in and descended from the selected folder, that the folder/file counting appears to be happening in the background because the dialog is still responsive, so I'm assuming what I want to do must be possible?

Comment: You can post a message to your property sheet page.

Comment: Posting a message from one thread to another (in this case, from a background worker thread to the main foreground/UI thread) would require use of `PostThreadMessage`, a method that posts messages not associated with any window.  The MSDN documentation is vague on this point, but it does not seem to indicate that there is any way to guarantee that a "non-relevant" or "non-standard" message received by the Shell's predefined Properties dialog message loop will be passed on to the dialog procedure for a page.

Comment: However, it has since occurred to me that one possible solution to this problem may be to use a message hook (i.e. `SetWindowsHookEx( WH_GETMESSAGE, ... )`).  I shall check this out along with the suggestion from @DenisAnisimov.

Comment: You don't need a message hook. Your property sheet page will get the message via the normal message pump I remind you that you have a window already: Your property sheet page is a window. Post the message to that window and process it in your dialog procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same. Worker thread is created with SHCreateThread. In UI thread I create timer. In OnTimer handler I query the worker thread about progress state and so on. Depend on answer I update UI of my sheet. If user close property dialog before worker thread finish calculation I just ask the worker thread to stop. When loop of the worker thread is finished shell32.dll will close thread by itself so I don`t need to wait.

Comment: I was not previously aware of `SHCreateThread` - I shall be sure to check it out.  Thanks for the tip.